# Android windowBackground attribute being ignored

Tags: java, android, material-design

Or kind of.

I've got an activity with a fragment container. Each Fragments layout has no background itself. I've already tried to set background to transparent - no effect.
Also I'm using [FragNav library](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) to handle fragment transactions.

The thing is - widnows background **shows correctly** in the editor xml preview.

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ng_window_background</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Drawable "ng_windows_background" is just a shape with solid color. Colors HEX is #FDA23.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

[XML preview example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjzCI.png) The background color is orange.

[Screenshot from device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Flf4.jpg) As you can see, the background color is gray.

What I've already tried:

- Changing fragment's layout background (**android:background**) color. Yes, it **works**, but it causes overdraw effect, which I am **trying to avoid** by using android:windowBackground attribute.
- Using **android:colorBackground** attribute, due to material components recommendations. No effect.
- Changing app's theme programmatically and in manifest. No effect.
- Changing *Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar* to AppCompat. No effect + I can't use AppCompat due to some issues.
- Changing background by getWindow().setBackgroundResource(); Neither in OnResume();

I guess it's an issue with MaterialComponents lib. I guess.

'can show any piece of code if necessary.

EDIT: manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packageName"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="AppClassPath"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=SplashScreenPath
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=MainActivityPath />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT #2:
Removed any functionality, leaving OnCreate() empty. No effect, so no problems with external libs.

help

Comment: Have you tried getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(yourDrawable) ?

Comment: No effect. I feel like it is a materialcomponents issue, cause I've seen kind of similar problems, but with MaterialButton.Or it's an issue with FragNav library, dunno.The thing that bothers me is that window background actually BEING CHANGED in the XML preview.

Comment: Yeah, it happens, you see everything perfect in XML, but when test it on the device. It does not work. Of what exactly are you trying to change the background? of activity? or of a fragment? Did you try it setting in onresume?

Comment: Eh, of an app? When the layouts background isn't set, the windows background shows? Default themes background, such as white, I guess. Will try set in OnResume(). Thank you.

Comment: No effect with onResume().

Comment: Maybe try setting AppTheme as theme of activity.

Comment: It set by default in manifest. Wait a minute, I've figured out something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was with an external lib, called 'com.infideap.drawerbehavior:drawer-behavior:1.0.1'. Will try to figure out what was wrong and post a proper solution.Yeah.